# Is this a phishing site?

Tags: discussion, phishing

http://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/questions

The above site looks exactly like stackoverflow.
Is it a phishing site ?
[image]

If it is a phishing site, what can be done?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do